# Dockerize a VPS / Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, docker, container, digital-ocean

Is it possible to create a docker image of my Ubuntu VPS including all the environment/setup, for example Nginx, Mysql together with their configurations, so that I can have an image which I can even use offline?

Is Docker cut for that, or are those exact requirements what a Virtual Machine is good for?